# Asynchronous insert in Azure Table

Tags: c#, asynchronous, azure, azure-table-storage

How to asynchronously save an entity to Windows Azure Table Service?

The code below works synchronously but raises an exception when trying to save asynchronously.

This statement:

```
context.BeginSaveChangesWithRetries(SaveChangesOptions.Batch,
    (asyncResult => context.EndSaveChanges(asyncResult)), null);
```

Results in System.ArgumentException: "The current object did not originate the async result. Parameter name: asyncResult".

Additionally, what's the correct pattern for creating the service context when saving asynchronously? Should I create a separate context for each write operation? Is it too expensive (e.g. requiring a call over the network)?

**TableStorageWriter.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Services.Client;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient;

namespace WorkerRole1
{
    public class TableStorageWriter
    {
        private const string _tableName = "StorageTest";
        private readonly CloudStorageAccount _storageAccount;
        private CloudTableClient _tableClient;

        public TableStorageWriter()
        {
            _storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
            _tableClient = _storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            _tableClient.CreateTableIfNotExist(_tableName);
        }

        public void Write(string message)
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
                var entity = new StorageTestEntity
                    {
                        Message = message,
                        PartitionKey = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", now),
                        RowKey = string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss.fff}-{1}", now, Guid.NewGuid())
                    };

                // Should I get this context before each write? It is efficient?
                TableServiceContext context = _tableClient.GetDataServiceContext();

                context.AddObject(_tableName, entity);

                // This statement works but it's synchronous
                context.SaveChangesWithRetries();

                // This attempt at saving asynchronously results in System.ArgumentException:
                // The current object did not originate the async result. Parameter name: asyncResult
                // context.BeginSaveChangesWithRetries(SaveChangesOptions.Batch,
                //                                  (asyncResult => context.EndSaveChanges(asyncResult)), null);
            }
            catch (StorageClientException e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
                Debug.WriteLine("Extended error info: {0} : {1}",
                                e.ExtendedErrorInformation.ErrorCode,
                                e.ExtendedErrorInformation.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
    }

    internal class StorageTestEntity : TableServiceEntity
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Called from **WorkerRole.cs**:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime;
using log4net;

namespace WorkerRole1
{
    public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
    {
        public override void Run()
        {
            var storageWriter = new TableStorageWriter();
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                storageWriter.Write("Working...");
            }
        }

        public override bool OnStart()
        {
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;
            return base.OnStart();
        }
    }
}
```

*Examples using Windows Azure SDK for .NET 1.8.*

Comment: For the async issue, what is the scope of context?  I wonder if there is a closure issue with the context.  

Regarding when to create the context, with a sleep time of 10000 in your loop, I don't think the performance of creating the table service context will be an issue.  However, I would generally lean towards creating it for each call unless you were going to use it heavily and constantly

Comment: Please take a look at the commented out code in Write() above. The scope of context is local. A closure is involved in my attempt, but I'm probably doing something wrong. In fact I'm looking for an example of how to do it. About performance, assume Write() will be heavily used; I'm looking for the fastest, safest way to insert asynchronously.

Comment: Have you tried making moving the scope of context up?  Make it a class member?

Comment: Same error if context is a private class member initialized in the constructor as in https://gist.github.com/4235952

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should call EndSaveChangesWithRetries instead of EndSaveChanges, as otherwise the IAsyncResult object returned by BeginSaveChangesWithRetries cannot be used by EndSaveChanges. So, could you please try changing your End method call as below?

```
context.BeginSaveChangesWithRetries(SaveChangesOptions.Batch,
    (asyncResult => context.EndSaveChangesWithRetries(asyncResult)),
    null);
```

And for your other question, I would recommend creating a new TableServiceContext for each call, as DataServiceContext is not stateless ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679618.aspx)) and the way you implemented TableStorageWriter.Write with the asynchronous call might allow concurrent operations. Actually, in Storage Client Library 2.0, we explicitly prevented concurrent operations that uses a single TableServiceContext object. Moreover, creating a TableServiceContext does not result in a request to Azure Storage.

Comment: Thank you! I should have read more carefully the class members list. Working version: https://gist.github.com/4236819

Comment: hi @serdar-ozler i would like to ask you, if the use of the method  CreateTableIfNotExist impact the the time of response and second the billing, i think i understood that azure will charge per actions and if i have a repetitive operation where i always first execute the createifExist and then the query do you know if this work like i think or im wrong, thanks for your orientation. if you see the Transactions by API name you will get an enormous quantity of CreateTable transactions.